# Using something like break in CSS

Tags: html, css

Since not everyone will be browsing the web on a computer, I need to use CSS to adapt to different screen sizes. I am working on the front-end part of the registration form, `register.php`. The issue is, on the computer the field name and field input position nicely. However, for the smaller screens (maximum width of 520px) I need the field name and field input to be on 
top/bottom of each other, field input being on top of its field name.

HTML:

```
#formBody{
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #3385ff;
    padding-left: 5%;
    padding-right: 5%;
    padding-top: 0.5em;
    padding-bottom: 0.5em;
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 50em;
    margin: auto;
}
.field{
    margin: auto;
    width: 66.6%;
}
.fieldDescription{
    width: 33%;
    color: black;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
.fieldInput{
    width: 33%;
    margin: auto;
}
.input{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #e6f0ff;
    border-style: none;
}
```

CSS:

```
<div id="formBody">
    <table>
        <form>
            <tr class="field">
                <td class="fieldDescription">
                    <p>First Name:</p>
                </td>
                <td class="fieldInput">
                    <input class="input" name="firstname" type="text">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </form>
    </table>
</div>
```

I used an HTML table to give each field its own space. I used the `<tr>` element to make a row for each field, and used two `<td>`element to put the field name and field input in its own column. This works great for a computer screen, but it doesn't work on the smaller screen (like a smartphone). If I use something like `<p class="fieldDescription">Fist Name:</p>` for the field name, then `<input class="fieldInput" name="firstName" type="text">` for the field input, then I'm hard coding only for small screens.

Is there a way to satisfy both screen sizes, without having to hard code it either way? I would prefer to not use Javascript. I would like to do it CSS.

[Click here for the HTML](https://gist.github.com/EliterScripts/6d42a79647b99490a336046d64ff2643)

[Click here for the CSS](https://gist.github.com/EliterScripts/9b39386292b5a95fa79030ed76d30241)

(both are on gist.github.com)

Comment: A [mcve] would be preferred to links to your code off-site. In fact, it's a requirement for SO

Comment: Better u can use div arrangement instead of table

Answer (score 0):

I'll highly recommend you to use [valid and semantic form elements](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/extensive-guide-web-form-usability/) like `label` and `fieldset`. But to address your question:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 520px) {
  #mainContainer {
    border-radius: 5px;
  }

  #formBody {
    border-radius: 0px;
  }

  .fieldDescription,
  .fieldInput {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
  }

  .fieldDescription p {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A Few Things to tell:

1. What you are looking for is making responsive designs. You should take a look to [Media Queries](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)
2. I Highly recomend not to use tables in cases like this, just use a table when u REALLY need a table
3. Here is a [LIVE EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/juanmamig/7s1wg3np/) with the *HTML* and *CSS* code of what you want to do. (Resize the browser to see).
4. Try not to style your forms with `<p> <tr> <td>` and so on... Use `<label>` instead.

Hope this work.

Answer (score 0):

@media + display:block; should be basicly what you need:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 520px) {
  table,/* to spray whole space as block does */
  tbody,/* because it is there even not in the code :) */
  tr,/* this too must be a block */
  td /* goal to reach to start from */{
    display: block;
  }
}
```

---

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 520px) {
  table,
  tbody,
  tr,
  td {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
/* copy to match snippet size */

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  table,
  tbody,
  tr,
  td {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
/* warning */

legend {
  color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div id="formBody">
  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Put that form around the table not in between table & tr tags !!</legend>
      <table>
        <tr class="field">
          <td class="fieldDescription">
            <p>First Name:</p>
          </td>
          <td class="fieldInput">
            <input class="input" name="firstname" type="text">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

---

And [demo including your style](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/akjGak)

---